# Owlcarousel 2 - elements not visible while translate3d()

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel, translate3d, owl-carousel-2

I'm using Owlcarousel 2 for sliding over multiple divs, the problem is that inside each "sliding-page" there are some elements positioned as absolute (relative not working neither), and they are not visible while animating, they just "blick-in" when the animation is finished.

This is what my html looks like

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel width-height-100">
  <div class="advert-bg lazyOwl owl-lazy" data-src="ad_preview_new.png">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-elg-9 pull-right position-absolute-text">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="advert-text gradient-white-bg">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-elg-3 pull-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h1>Suikervrij beleg</h1>
                        <p>
                            Suikervrij beleg op de
                            brood, beschuit of pannenkoek?
                            Met onze suikervrije confituur
                            en chocopasta kan en mag het!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="logo.png" class="image-logo" >
  </div>
  <div class="advert-bg lazyOwl owl-lazy" data-src="ad_preview_new.png">
    <div style="margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:100px;height:100px;display:block;background:red;">
        fds
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-elg-9 pull-right position-absolute-text">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="advert-text gradient-white-bg">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-elg-3 pull-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h1>Suikervrij beleg</h1>
                        <p>
                            Suikervrij beleg op de
                            brood, beschuit of pannenkoek?
                            Met onze suikervrije confituur
                            en chocopasta kan en mag het!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="logo.png" class="image-logo" >
  </div>
  <div class="advert-bg lazyOwl owl-lazy" data-src="http://localhost:8888/ad_preview_new2.png">
    <img src="logo2.png" class="image-logo" >
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my JS file

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
    pagination: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    loop:true,
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    items : 1,
    itemsDesktop : false,
    itemsDesktopSmall : false,
    itemsTablet: false,
    itemsMobile : false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    lazyContent:true
  });

});
```

What can I do to make all the elements visible even while they are sliding-in (when they are sliding-out it works).
It was working with Owlcarousel 1.

Answer (score 3):

In the **owl.carousel.js** file

**REPLACE**

```
transform: 'translate3d(' + coordinate + 'px,0px,0px)'
```

**WITH**

```
transform: 'translate3d(' + (coordinate-1) + 'px,0px,0px)'
```

And, in case of the **owl.carousel.min.js** file

**REPLACE**

```
transform: 'translate3d("+b+"px,0px,0px)'
```

**WITH**

```
transform: 'translate3d("+(b-1)+"px,0px,0px)'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `transform: 'translate3d("+(b-1)+"px,0px,0px)'` this didn't work with me but this did it `transform: 'translate3d("+(-b)+"px,0px,0px)'
`

Answer (score 0):

It seems it happens in Chrome, not Firefox.
Possible solution is to modify the css:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item { -webkit-backface-visibility: visible; }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue, 'relative' content was not showing and finally I found out that it's related to css 'transition' effect. So adding this to parent element fixed mine:

`transition: all 0.3s ease;`